# Google Drive API - Call to a member function on a non-object when trying to update a file

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to access and update a file in my Google Drive with PHP. Everything goes fine until I try to call $file_to_update->setTitle("NEW TITLE").

I can download the file's metadata, but I can't update anything.

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';



$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('');
$client->setClientSecret('');
$client->setRedirectUri('');
$client->setScopes(array(''));

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

//Request authorization
print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);


retrieveAllFiles($service);

function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
$result = array();
$pageToken = NULL;

  do {
try {
  $parameters = array();
  if ($pageToken) {
    $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
  }
  $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);


  $fileIDs = array();

  $file = ($files[items]);
  foreach($file as $f){
    array_push($fileIDs, $f["id"]);
    print $f["id"]."\n";
  }

  $str = $fileIDs[1];

  $file_to_update = $service->files->get($str);

  $file_to_update->setTitle("NEW TITLE");

} catch (Exception $e) {
  print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  $pageToken = NULL;
}
} while ($pageToken);
 return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to $service->files->get($str) is not returning object.

if you check at function:

> ```
> public function get($fileId, $optParams = array()) {
>   $params = array('fileId' => $fileId);
>   $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
>   $data = $this->__call('get', array($params));
>   if ($this->useObjects()) {
>     return new Google_DriveFile($data);
>   } else {
>     return $data;
>   }
> }
> ```

It checks if you want to work with objects, or not:

> $this->useObjects()

You need to configure 'use_objects' to 'true' in your api config.php file, it is set to 'false' by default.

> 'use_objects' => false,

Comment: Thank you - I was struggling with this for a while